# Partition a square

Tags: contest-math

Compute the smallest positive integer $n$ such that， for any given integer $p\geq n$, we can partition a given square into $p$ number of squares (the small squares are not necessarily congruent)

I think the answer is 4, clearly square can be partition into the perfect square number pieces.

Comment: How do you partition a square into 5 squares? I think it has to be greater than 5 ...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee clearly you cannot try all the numbers out, we need an algorthim or find a parrtern

Comment: I was just pointing out that your guess of 4 isn't right unless you can find an arrangement for 5 squares, and even then you'd be left to prove the higher number cases

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee oh yes, 5 is feasible I think but I can't upload the graph

Answer (score 4):

Given any dissection, we can find one with three more squares by cutting one of the squares into $4$.  We can find dissections with $6, 7,$ and $8$ squares, so we can find one with all larger numbers.  We can't find one with $5$, so $n=6$.  The $6$ is a $2 \times 2$ plus five $1 \times 1$ squares, the $7$ is three $2 \times 2$ squares plus four $1 \times 1$, and the $8$ is a $3 \times 3$ plus seven $1 \times 1$ squares as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! A minor note: you can use the simple cutting into $4$ instead of $7$, just a tiny bit simpler.